# Node application, manage module dependencies

Tags: node.js, build, gulp, node-modules

I'm new in node development and I'm doing a little bit of training.
My folder structure looks like this:

```
node-test
|
|   
+---build
|   |
|   +---node_modules
|   |
|   +---public
|   |
|   +---server
|   |
|   \---main.js
|
|---src
    |
    +---node_modules
    |
    +---public
    |
    +---server
    |
    |---.gitignore
    |
    \---main.ts
```

I'm using Gulp to build source code to `build` folder maintaining the structure.

I'm facing some problem related Node dependencies.
Initially I used `gulp-npm-files` to copy required dependencies into `build\node_modules` using all the examples found on [package page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-npm-files) but always some dependency is missing. So for the moment gulp copies the entire `src\node_modules` in `build\node_modules`. Certainly is not the right way but express works and I can see static HTML.

I've also another problem about dependencies:

```
this.app.use(express.static(RouterContants.PublicDirectory));
```

This line sets the only folder that the browser can access, right? OK, then how can I access node_modules?

How dependencies have to been managed correctly?
Any suggestions and advices are welcome.

Thank you

Comment: Focus your question on one thing, explain that one thing clearly and include a [mcve].

Comment: I think any build with node_modules directly in your out-dir is wrong. webpack took care of all those worries for me, and it's so versatile I never used gulp/grunt again. Sure, it's not a 1to1 replacement but who even needs script runners with webpack around? This is me being very opinionated of course, but the question is leading.

Comment: Understood. So I moved project root at upper level and now src, build and node_modules are at the same level. Then there's not need to copy node_modules in build folder. Now I'm also trying webpack. I'm using TypeScript to write code, so I thought to write all code in src and copy to build maintaining folder structure in order to not have ts, js and map files all together. I saw that with webpack I can bundle the modules that browser needs and put the result file inside public folder. Do you think acceptable solution? Should I bundle my code in public folder too? Thank you

Comment: I notice that using my `app.tsx` as entry point webpack automatically includes in the bundle the needed node dependencies. Great! But at the moment I didn't found how perform the other operations that actually gulp do. I opened a [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44424484/1752757) for this other problem. I will write the temporary solution, could be helpful for someone.