# Build this node project using only gulp or webpack

Tags: node.js, typescript, build, gulp, webpack-2

My project has this folder structure:

```
node
|   .gitignore
|   gulpfile.js
|   package.json
|   tsconfig.json
|   webpack.config.js
|   
+---build
|   |   debug.js
|   |   main.js
|   |   
|   +---client
|   |   +---scripts
|   |   |       bundle.js
|   |   |       
|   |   \---views
|   |           index.html
|   |           
|   |               
|   \---server
|       |   constants.js
|       |   server.js
|       |   
|       \---router
|           |   constants.js
|           |   router.js
|           |   
|           \---routes
|                   base.js
|                   index.js
|                   
+---gulp
|   |   constants.js
|   |   
|   \---tasks
|           default.js
|           html.js
|           typescript.js
|           
\---src
    |   main.ts
    |   
    +---client
    |   +---app
    |   |   |   app.tsx
    |   |   |   
    |   |   \---components
    |   |           hello.tsx
    |   |           
    |   \---views
    |           index.html
    |               
    \---server
        |   constants.ts
        |   server.ts
        |   
        \---router
            |   constants.ts
            |   router.ts
            |   
            \---routes
                    base.ts
                    index.ts
```

Gulp is used to copy HTML and compile TypeScript in `build` folder maintaining folder structure. But I didn't found how to also bundle front-end code and node dependencies in order to make these avaiable in `build/client`. After some suggestion and research I used Webpack to create `bundle.js`.

Now I've the expected result but I wonder if there is a way to only Gulp or Webpack, in order to simplify the build process.

Comment: I believe you can use [`ts-loader`](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader) to compile TypeScript files with Webpack. I'm not sure about the HTML files, but there must be something for that as well.

Comment: Yes, to compile front-end code inside `src/client` I already use `ts-loaded` but what about back-end code? I saw that it's possibile to indicate multiple entry points with Webpack but has it sense to bundle also back-end code? Or there is some way to simply compile and copy in `build` maintaining folder structure? About HTML I saw that it's possible to generate it. I will also try this way though I don't need it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I wonder if there is a way to only Gulp or Webpack

These are different tools.

- Gulp: Task runners. Runs code segments
- Webpack: Module bundler. Bundles code in a manner that can be used in the browser.

If you want a bundler (which you do) *gulp will not suffice*.

Comment: Then to build a project with a project like this gulp and webpack is an acceptable solution?

Comment: Yes. My personal preference is to just use npm scripts (another way to run code segments) with webpack.